# Opportunity Owner- Field Tracking History not appearing

Tags: history-tracking

I have the 'Field History Tracking' enabled for 'Opportunity Owner' field on Opportunity object in my sandbox, but i'm not able to find the 'Owner' field changes in 'Opportunity Field History' related list.

I've tried almost everything to debug, from Data Loader, Audit Trail with no success.

Please help me out over this.

Comment: I assume you have actually tested by changing the Opportunity Owner, It won;t appear in the field history related list for New. Also be aware there are two related lists if querying via SOQL: `OpportunityHistories` and `OpportunityFieldHistories` - you want the latter

Comment: I have checked with SOQL query also with no success.

Any other way around?